# Prove that a compact metric space is also complete without using Heinel-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, complete-spaces

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Prove that $X$ is also complete.

Here's a more direct way:

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a cauchy sequence in $X$. That is, for any $\epsilon /2 >0$ there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon /2$ for $n,m \geq N_0$.

$X$ is compact, that is that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent sub-sequence, that is $\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}=x_0$, ir that for any $\epsilon /2 >0$ there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_{n_k},x_0)<\epsilon /2$ for $k \geq N_1$. Note that $k>n_k$ should be satisfied.

So we want the cauchy sequence to be convergent, that is for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n,x_0)<\epsilon $ for $n \geq N$.

Taking $N=max(N_0,N_1)$ and by triangle inequality we have:
$d(x_n,x_0) \leq  d(x_n,x_{n_k}) + d(x_{n_k},x_0) \rightarrow d(x_n,x_0) <  \epsilon /2 + \epsilon /2 = \epsilon$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is o.k.

But you should write $N=max (N_0,N_1) $

Comment: OK, I've just fixed it. Thanks!